# How can I count and show the number of times a row appears within multiple joined tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I wrote the below query which shows me ApplicationIDs associated with two specific ables.  I need the results to return the number of times each Applications.AppID appears in those tables next to the row with the application name.  Ive used distinct because in my results I only want the name to appear once but have a number next to it indicating how many times it has been used.  Examples below.  Ive written count conditions before but only for single tables.

```
  SELECT 0 AppId   ,
         'Select an Application' ApplicationName
union all
  select .1        ,
         '--All--'
union all
  SELECT DISTINCT
         Applications.AppId ,
         Applications.ApplicationName
  FROM ImpactedApplications ,
       SupportingApplications 
  JOIN applications              ON SupportingApplications.Appid = applications.appid
  JOIN ImpactedApplications Apps on SupportingApplications.AppId = Applications.AppId
```

Returns something like this:

```
0.0   Select an Application
0.1   --All--
12.0  APP A
59.0  APP B
60.0  APP C
71.0  APP D
74.0  APP E
121.0 APP F
124.0 APP G
130.0 APP H
```

I want it to return something like this:

```
0.0   Select an Application
0.1   --All--
12.0  APP A 1
59.0  APP B 2
60.0  APP C 1
71.0  APP D 4
74.0  APP E 3
121.0 APP F 1
124.0 APP G 2
130.0 APP H 2
```

Any help is appreciated thank you.

Adding Results from Help Query

```
12 APP A 17161
59 APP B 51483
60 APP C 85805
71 APP D 17161
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you do realize that order is **unspecified** unless you order the result set using `order by`? That means there is no guarantee that the first two selects in your `union all` will come first.

So, let's strip those two out as they are really extraneous to the actual problem. Let us consider the core `select`:

select distinct
         Applications.AppId ,
         Applications.ApplicationName
  from ImpactedApplications   ,
       SupportingApplications 
  JOIN applications              ON SupportingApplications.Appid = applications.appid
  JOIN ImpactedApplications Apps on SupportingApplications.AppId = Applications.AppId

and dissect it.

**Problem #1.**
`select distinct` is often a *code smell* indicating that you don't have the correct join criteria or you don't correclty understand the cardinality of the relationships involved.

**Problem #2.**
Indeed, this is the case. You are mixing old-school, pre-ISO/ANSI joins with ISO/ANSI joins. Since the first two tables in the FROM clause are joined pre-ISO/ANSI style, and you have no `where` clause with criteria to join them, The above `select` statement is exactly identical to

select distinct
         a.AppId ,
         a.ApplicationName
  from       ImpactedApplications   ia
  cross join SupportingApplications sa
  join       applications           a    on sa.Appid = a.appid
  join       ImpactedApplications   Apps on sa.AppId = a.AppId

I'm pretty sure you didn't intend to generate the cartesian product of the 2 tables. You haven't described the table schema, but my suspicion, from your problem statement

> I need the results to return the number of times each Applications.AppID
>   appears in those tables next to the row with the application name.

is that you want something more along these lines:

```
select AppId           = a.AppId           ,
       AppName         = a.ApplicationName ,
       ImpactedCount   = coalesce( ia.Cnt , 0 ) ,
       SupportingCount = coalesce( sa.Cnt , 0 ) ,
       Total           = coalesce( ia.Cnt , 0 )
                       + coalesce( sa.Cnt , 0 )
from      Applications           a
left join ( select AppId = t.AppId ,
                   Cnt   = count(*)
            from ImpactedApplications t
            group by t.AppId
          ) ia on ia.AppId = a.AppId
left join ( select AppId = t.AppId ,
                   Cnt   = count(*)
            from SupportingApplications t
            group by t.AppId
          ) sa on sa.AppId = a.AppId
```

If you want to restrict the results to just those rows with non-zero values, you could change the `left join` clauses to `join`, but that would mean you would only get those rows that have a non zero value for both. Instead, add a where clause to restrict the result set:

```
where sa.Cnt > 0
   OR ia.Cnt > 0
```

In addition to filtering out any rows where both counts are zero, it also removes rows where both rows have a `null` count, indicating that no match occurred in the `left join`.

Comment: This works great!  I can remove the impacted and supporting count from this and just use the totals also!  Also,  Is there a way I can limit it to only items that have a total?  Right now its returning values of 0 for many of them.

Comment: Perfect! This did exactly what I needed! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

DISTINCT is logically equivalent to a GROUP BY:

```
SELECT Applications.AppId, Applications.ApplicationName
   ,COUNT(*)
FROM SupportingApplications 
INNER JOIN    applications ON SupportingApplications.Appid = applications.appid
INNER JOIN ImpactedApplications as Apps on SupportingApplications.AppId = Applications.AppId 
GROUP BY Applications.AppId, Applications.ApplicationName
```

Comment: Thank you for the idea.  When I tried this I received an unusually large number.  In the 10s of thousands when im certain it should be only 2 or three. I included the results in my original post.  Any idea what causes that?

Comment: There's no condition to join to the 2nd copy of ImpactedApplications resulting in a cross join. You probably don't need it at all, so simply remove it. Edited my answer.

Comment: This works, however it reduces the number values to something much lower but still in the hundreds.  If I delete the Inner Join on ImpactedApplications it works. but I do need the total aggregate of the two tables.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 0 AppId, 'Select an Application' ApplicationName union all
                                select .1,'--All--' union all
SELECT DISTINCT app.AppId, app.ApplicationName,count(app.AppId)
FROM  SupportingApplications sa 
INNER JOIN    applications app ON sa.Appid = applications.appid
--INNER JOIN ImpactedApplications as Apps on sa.AppId = app.AppId
group by app.AppId, app.ApplicationName
```

It doesn't look like your doing anything with ImpactedApplications table, so idk maybe remove that line

Comment: Hey there.  Thanks for the feedback.  I am using impacted applications.  I need it to look in both Supporting and Impacting for AppIds.